# How to use a4j:commandLink in JSF 1.2

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2, ajax4jsf

How to use a4j command link button for Edit button in a jsf 1.2 scrollableDataTable table.
When Edit button is pressed it should render it to next panel as read only.

```
<rich:scrollableDataTable id="renderingProviderRules"  
styleClass="TMargin10Px"       width="400px" height="80px"
frozenColCount="0" value="#{maintainClients.visibleClientRenderingProviderRules}"
var="clientRendering" ajax="true" selectionMode="single">
<rich:column>
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="Business Rule" />
</f:facet>
<h:outputText
value="#{clientRendering.renderingProviderRules.renderingProviderRuleENUM}" />
</rich:column>
<rich:column>
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="Start Date" />
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{clientRendering.startDate}" />
</rich:column>
<rich:column>
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="End Date" />
</f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{clientRendering.endDate}" />
</rich:column>
<rich:column>
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="" />
</f:facet>
<c:if test="#{clientRendering.endDate}">    



 If edit button is pressed here it should render the content in the row to next panel
 as read only                                      
<a4j:commandLink value="Edit" styleClass="Edit"
title="Click to edit Plan" 
 />
</c:if>
</rich:column></rich:scrollableDataTable>
<h:panelGrid columns="7" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5"
styleClass="GenericGrid" columnClasses="GenericPanels">

<h:outputLabel value="Business Rule"
for="renderingProviderBusinessRule" styleClass="LFloat">
</h:outputLabel>

<h:panelGroup>
<!-- force empty column -->
</h:panelGroup>

<h:outputLabel value="Start Date" for="renderingStartDate"
styleClass="LFloat">
</h:outputLabel>
<h:panelGroup>
<!-- force empty column -->
</h:panelGroup>

<h:outputLabel value="Edit End Date" for="renderingEditEndDate"
styleClass="LFloat">
</h:outputLabel>

<h:panelGroup>
<!-- force empty column -->
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup>
<!-- force empty column -->
</h:panelGroup>


<h:inputText id="renderingProviderBusinessRule" value="" required="true" />

<h:panelGroup>
<!-- force empty column -->
</h:panelGroup>

<h:inputText id="renderingStartDate" value=""
style="width: 100px" required="true" />
<h:panelGroup>
<!-- force empty column -->
</h:panelGroup>

<a4j:outputPanel id="renderingEditEndDate" layout="block">
<rich:calendar value="" datePattern="MM/dd/yyyy"
styleClass="LFloat" inputStyle="width: 80px" label="End Date"
enableManualInput="true" zindex="1000" disabled="" />
</a4j:outputPanel>

<h:panelGroup>
<!-- force empty column -->
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup styleClass="RFloat">
<a4j:commandButton id="OK" value="OK"
styleClass="GenericButton OkButton" />
</h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGrid>
</fieldset>
</h:panelGroup>
```

My Question here use a4j edit so that contents of the row in scrollable table is rerendered as read only text in the next panel for respective fields.

Comment: Post *only* relevant code

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149141/richfaces-show-details-in-popup-commandbutton-action-and-popuppanel/21149308#21149308) for inspiration. It shows row details in popup. Can be used for edit purpose.